# Using multiple fields on Filter Pipe | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was wondering how would I use Pipe to filter a json object using multiple inputs fields, here's my code so far with only one field filtering by name:

**TS**

```
members = [
    {name:'Carl', country:"Brazil"},
    {name:'John', country:"United States"},
    {name:'Madhu', country:"India"}
  ]
```

**PIPE.TS**

```
  transform(members: any, term: any): any {
//check if search term is undefined
if (term === undefined) return members;

//return updated members array
return members.filter(function(member){
  return member.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
})
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" name="any"/>

          <li *ngFor="let member of members | filter:term">

              <h3>{{member.name}}</h3>
              <span>{{member.country}}</span>

          </li>
```

I want to add an extra input field where it will search for the country.

**EDIT:**

It worked with the following code:

**TS COMPONENT**

```
 fields: any  = { name: "", country: "" };
  filters: any = { name: "", country: "" };

  updateFilters(): void {
      this.filters = Object.assign({}, this.fields);
      console.log(this.filters);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="any" [(ngModel)] = "fields.name" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()"/>
          <input type="text" name="anyy" [(ngModel)] = "fields.country" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()"/>

<li *ngFor="let member of members | filter: filters">
            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);margin-bottom:15px">
              <h3>{{member.name}}</h3>
              <span>{{member.country}}</span>
            </div>
          </li>
```

**PIPE.TS**

```
  transform(members: any, filters: any): any {
    return members.filter(item => {
    return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filters.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && item.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(filters.country.toLowerCase()) >= 0);

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an object instead of multiple fields:

```
<li *ngFor="let member of members | filter: filters">
```

In your component's class:

```
filters: any = { name: "ex", country: "a country" };
```

UPDATE:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "fields.name" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()"/>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "fields.country" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()"/>
```

In your component:

```
fields: any  = { name: "", country: "" };
filters: any = { name: "", country: "" };

updateFilters(): void {
    this.filters = Object.assign({}, this.fields);
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked, I suppose the <input> should look like this?
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filters.name" name="anyy"/>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filters.country" name="any"/>

Comment: I understood your answer, but how would I do it with multiple input fields?

Comment: There's no error, your code doesn't answer how I would use multiple fields.

Comment: Ok, try to make your pipe impure. Look at the updated answer

Comment: Didn't worked, shouldn't we change something on the transform function on PIPE.TS? Also, how the [(ngModel)] on the inputs should be like?

Comment: Wait a minute so I can see what the problem is

Comment: This is the problem:  angular pipe don't detect any changes in a property of the filters object. To solve the problem, we have to change the reference of the entire object (by using Object.assign here)  whenever a change is detected. The last updated answer now works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155499/discussion-between-gustavo-and-faly).